# c++ operator associativity / string concatenation / move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11

*Update*: Sorry, I was wrong, binary `+` is in fact left-associative. But nevertheless the question still counts, as there is a complementary problem.

---

I read in C/C++, the `+` operator is right-associative. That means that given `std::string`s `a, b, c` all initialized to some nonzero-length,

```
string d = a + b + c;
```

should be fully equivalent to (i.e., producing the same executable) to

```
string d = a + (b + c);
```

Now, it seems that this is rather unfortunate: it would make more sense to extend `a` by `b` and then by `c` as in

```
string d = (a + b) + c;
```

because that should run with `b.size() + c.size()` copy operations given that no reallocations are needed.

So, should I in practice use parens / separate `+=` assignments or does the spec allow for further optimizations to make the paren-less version equally effective?

I'm mainly concerned with C++11 here and would also be grateful for (yet another) post on move semantics et.al. if this applies here.

Comment: [Proof that it's wrong.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c6360aa6549cd6a1fb128595bf0a5bec-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)

Comment: The spec allows **all optimisations** that preserve observable behaviour and even goes as far as allowing some that don't preserve observable behaviour.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes, it proves that the left addition is done first, because it does not add the result of a pointer addition to the string ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Well, if it was parsed as `s + ("def" + "ghi")`, it wouldn't compile. I agree it doesn't *prove* anything if you consider only standard quotations as proof, though.

Comment: @ArneMertz There are no pointers involved in that code whatsoever.

Comment: @H2CO3 string literals have type `char const*`, which is a pointer type

Comment: @chris Oh, erm, right. Ignore me.

Comment: @ArneMertz No, string literals have type `char[N + 1]` in C and `const char [N + 1]` in C++, where N is the length of the string.

Comment: @H2CO3, Technically a reference to that ([as shown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bc9bfc51281848f9902388459ed96a0a-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)), not that it usually makes a difference.

Comment: @H2CO3 well, right, you got me. But attempting to find an operator overload for the addition, the compiler will decay them to `char const*`

Comment: @ArneMertz yeah, that's correct. In the meantime, I became aware of what Chris meant by "it wouldn't compile", because `"string" + "literal"` surely wouldn't. (I just failed to understand your comment at first.)

Comment: Regarding your update: you should probably rewrite this question to be specific about the complementary problem.

Comment: Move it to meta guys.

Comment: @chris nah, it's not a reference (see §2.14.5, paragraph 8). That's just a consequence of `decltype` rules having exceptions and corner cases, as befits any C++ feature.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Shoot, that's right. Now I'm trying to remember exactly where it is I keep seeing the reference, since the standard only says array of const characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the *unary* `operator+` is right associative (as far as a unary operator can be), the *binary* `operator+` is in fact left associative.

**To address your concerns:**

```
string d = a + b + c;
```

This first will give a temporary with the result of `(a+b)`. There is no way around that temporary, because a and b cannot be changed. The temporary will reserve at least `a.size()+b.size()` bytes in memory, the contents of `a` and `b` will be copied into that new memory.

Then `c` will be added to the temporary, calling `operator+(string&& lhs,const string& rhs)`. This will take the temporary and add the contents of `c` to it, probably after a reallocation to compensate the need for more space and copying the `a.size()+b.size()` bytes from the old to the new memory. After that, the contents of `c` will get appended to the temporary in the new memory.

Then the move constructor will kick in, taking owndership of the memory of the temporary.

In total that gives at most two (re)allocations (one in each `operator+`), one deallocation (during the reallocation in `tmp + c`) and four copies (a, b, c, and the temporary during the reallocation). There are *not* `a.size()+b.size()` copy operations, because string contents can be copied en bloc (memcpy/memmove), because the char arrays are PODs that need not be copied one after the other.

The only thing that *could* be optimized here is the temporary reserving enough memory for the end result while executing `a+b`. While from a language/library point of view there is nothing that can done about this, an optimizer *could* theoretically see the allocation and conditional reallocation and do the right thing by reserving enough memory from the start. I have no idea how easy such optimizations are to implement, but I guess detecting things like `string z = a + b + c + d + e + f...` is not that easy, so I would not count on it.

Ayways, the temporaries typically wont hurt your program performance, because string operations like these seldom take place in performance critical places.

If you absolutely *must* enhance the performance of that operation, this is the way to go:

```
string d;
d.reserve(a.size() + b.size() + c.size());
d.append(a);
d.append(b);
d.append(c);
```

leading to one allocation during the reserve call and exactly the three necessary copies.

Comment: Ok. I'll accept this answer because it's technically correct and I guess it's counterproductive to continue the question in this state.

Comment: @JoSo I added a discussion about what happens during that line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing unary plus with addition.